# javascript big arrays or objects: browser performance and memory

Tags: javascript

I wonder if working with arrays (or objects) which contain about 100 000 elements (properties) can cause performance or memory problems in browsers when frequently access them using indexOf, slice etc. Are there some recommendations for working with big arrays in modern browsers?

My particular case. I have the following structure:

tack01: [array of elements 10 000 in average] 
...
tack0n: [array of elements 10 000 in average]

tracks average amount is 10.

element looks like {id: "xa432fds", some properties}

During the runtime I need to access any of the element knowing providing it's id.

If I use this structure without transformation I need to perform search throught all tracks and use indexOf to find element with Id.

So I deside to create an index object which has following structure:
indexObj = {id1: reference to element with id1, id2: reference to element with id2}

to access a certain element I just need to access indexObj[id], is it right solution for my case?

All this should be performed on the client side.

Comment: http://jsperf.com is your friend.

Comment: I would recommend using pagination if you can. If you have an object of that size in the browser, you will definitely see some performance issues. If you can do any processing in the backend(if any of your objects are coming from a db), I would recommend doing it there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's a very broad question.

I'd say the primary recommendation would be to really deeply understand what you're working with. Arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're objects with all the normal plumbing of JavaScript normal objects. Array indexes aren't numbers, aren't offsets into some memory table*; they're string keys in a dictionary-like map. Once you embrace the fact that arrays are just objects, it may open up new ways of structuring or accessing your data such that you can avoid expensive operations like `indexOf`.

*(* Barring JavaScript engine optimizations, of course. And engines **do** optimize.)*

---

**Update**: Looking at your edit, yes, transforming the data so that you can look up tracks by using their `id` as a property name (`indexObj[id]`) is what I'd recommend. Then, instead of the expensive linear search required by `indexOf`, you get the benefit of the JavaScript engine's handling of property names, which will typically be a much more efficient lookup (b-trees and/or hash structures, etc.).

Once you've created your indexed version, if you can release the array version, the memory consumed by the array and its property names (`"0"`, `"1"`, etc.) can be eligible for reclamation, which may be useful (your individual tracks will remain in memory because you're referencing them from the indexed structure).

Comment: Thanks, i added an update to my post in which described the case.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: Updated the answer in response.

Comment: Excellent link! My summary: Arrays are objects under the hood... Arrays are sparse... Array indices are converted to strings under the hood... Don't use for..in to loop through an array, use .forEach or the traditional method

Comment: Hi! I'm really struck by this: "Once you embrace the fact that arrays are just objects". Can you elaborate more? I'm willing to read it if you will ^^

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw - I'd be happy to elaborate, but I'm not sure how much more there is to say other than what I've said above and in the [linked blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)...? Here's an example of an array's object nature: `const a = []; a.example = 42; console.log(a.example); // 42` Similarly: `for (const name in [1]) { console.log(typeof name, name); }` logs `string 0` because the property names in objects are strings (or Symbols). If arrays weren't objects, you'd expect a `for-in` to fail or to loop over numbers... :-)