# Representing a 2D point as an array

Tags: javascript, performance

1. In Javascript I can represent a 2D point (1,2) either as an object `{x:1, y:2}` or as 
   an array `[1,2]`. Is the last one significantly better when it comes to performance?
2. If at some point of my program I decide to add a property to a point `v` (such as `v.next = u`) and `v` is represented as an array, will I loose that **[*]** performance gain?

**[*]** assuming the answer to 1 is **YES**.

Comment: In javascript everything is an object, even the arrays, so I see no difference, do what is easier to code maintain

Comment: Well, but in practice I think that indexing an array is much faster than accessing an object's field (since the later requires some kind of hashing and the former is really a memory access, provided that the array is not sparse and it's a "real" array (not just an object with numerical fields))

Comment: I mean, maybe by the standard everything is the same thing, but I really think (or hope that) a javascript engine doesn't make a hash lookup at each array access.

Comment: Check this question out for some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript

Comment: After reading http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/ , I think that this depends on a lot of code details that control how much optimization the engine can/will do.  So you really have to talk about specific code, at which point you might as well just ask jsperf.

Answer (score 0):

Taking my own advice (comment above), googling for 'array object point site:jsperf.com' leads to http://jsperf.com/point-array-vs-point-object/2 , which suggests that, at least in Chrome and Node.js (V8) today, objects may be be the better choice.

But if I wanted to put the pedal to the metal and was mostly working with arrays of points, I'd also benchmark code that forces all args to integers (`x=x|0`) and uses a one-dimensional array, performing the address arithmetic for x/y by hand, and writing an ES6 iterator for it.  If done carefully, this can avoid creating an object for most points, even when manipulating them.