# Javascript : declare array

Tags: javascript

what's difference to declare array:

```
var tab={};
```

AND

```
var tab=[];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array vs. Object efficiency in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference:

```
tab = {} // an empty object (or a blank object)
tab = [] // an array (which is actually an object too)
```

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition:](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)** What is an array? It's simply a list (a sequence) of values. Instead
>   of using one variable to store one value, you can use one array
>   variable to store any number of values as elements of the array. To declare a variable that contains an empty array, you use square
>   brackets with nothing between them:
>
> `var a = [];`
>
> To define an array that has three elements, you do this:
>
> `var a = [1, 2, 3];`
>
> The elements contained in an array are indexed with consecutive
>   numbers starting from zero. The first element has index (or position)
>   `0`, the second has index `1`, and so on.To access an array element, you specify the index of that element inside square brackets. So, `a[0]` gives you the first element of the array `a`, `a[1]` gives you the second, and so on.

**Difference:**

> An object is similar to an array, but with the difference that you
>   define the keys yourself. You're not limited to using only numeric
>   indexes and you can use friendlier keys, such as first_name, age, and
>   so on.

```
var tab = {
    name: 'Ninja'
};
```

Comment: an array is always an object.