# How are {} vs [] data structures handled in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I come from a non-computer science background, and am looking for some kind of theoretical guidance in how to choose/evaluate/think about data structures.

The immediate aim is a schema for CouchDB documents and be able to retrieve millions back at a time and parse their contents efficiently.

In particular, I want to be able to scan a document's keys (which are date strings). Below is a (poor I'm sure) test to see efficiency differences between:

1. Iterating through object keys, checking if they are dates and if they are parsing the dates
2. Iterating through an array within an abject where you KNOW all the values are dates, and parsing the dates
3. Accessing dates by an explicitly named 'date' attribute.

Even this test makes it evident which is the most efficient. **How can I find out more about how these data structures 'work' when compiling/interpreting JavaScript (or just how different data structures are handled in general)?**

```
var s1 = {
x: 1,
"10 March 2016": "2",
"11 March 2016": "asdfasdf",
"12 March 2016": "asdfasdfas"
};
s1 = JSON.stringify(s1);

var s2 = {
    x: 1,
    readings: [
        ["10 March 2016", "asdf"],
        ["10 March 2016", "asdf"],
        ["10 March 2016", "asdf"]
    ]
};
s2 = JSON.stringify(s2);

var s3 = {
    x: 1,
    readings: [{
        date: "10 March 2016",
        reading: "asdfasd"
    }, {
        date: "10 March 2016",
        reading: "asdfasd"
    }, {
        date: "10 March 2016",
        reading: "asdfasd"
    }]
};
s3 = JSON.stringify(s3);

var iterations = 9000000;

// Testing s1
var t1 = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    var t1o = JSON.parse(s1);
    for (var k in t1o) {
        if(new Date(k)) {
            var d = t1o[k];
        }
    }
}
var t2 = new Date();
console.log("S1: ", t2 - t1); // 2nd fastest

// Testing s2
var t1 = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    var t1o = JSON.parse(s2);
    for (var k in t1o.readings) {
        if(new Date(k)) {
            var d = t1o.readings[k];
        }
    }
}
var t2 = new Date();
console.log("S2: ", t2 - t1); // slowest

// Testing s3
var t1 = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    var t1o = JSON.parse(s3);
    for (var j = 0; j < t1o.readings.length; j++) {
        var d = new Date(t1o.readings[j].date);
    };
}
var t2 = new Date();
console.log("S3: ", t2 - t1); // fastest
```

One printout for the above is:

```
S1:  32002
S2:  50062
S3:  25442
```

Comment: In theory, arrays are just objects and objects are the only kind of data structure that exist in JS. In practice, JavaScript engines might optimize arrays when properly used as only arrays.

Comment: see also [Array vs. Object efficiency in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17295056/1048572)

Comment: Worth a read, even if a few years old: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/