# how to decide when to use array or objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I had an interview where the person asked me this question. Can anyone explains all the aspects so that i have a clear idea which structure to use when.

Comment: use the structure appropriate to the data

Comment: To be simple: Do you need named keys? Object! Don't? Array! The rest is opinion based.

Comment: Here is a good read for you: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them

Comment: Beside this, an `array` is an `object` too in JS.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks...actually he asked that both of them can do the same job at the end..Is there a striking difference i can put up which separates them totally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays:

- Arrays provide order, Object's don't *(at least not yet)*.
- Arrays can be optimized *(speed and even the memory footprint)*, when used as non sparse lists with items of the same type.
- Arrays provide a bunch of functions to work with this data-structure

Objects:

- Objects are more generic
- Using the Object as a Dictionary: lookups are faster than iterating over an Array to find the right item. 
  `return itemsById[id]`
- Code for Objects with the same hidden class can also be optimized.

Conclusion:

**Arrays:** use them if you think of the data as a list; same type improves performance but ain't a requirement.
To be more precise: lists have no gaps *(missing indices)*, the data may have gaps, but the list shouldn't. If the list would have gaps, then the index has a meaning beyond just order, and it's probably a Dictionary with numeric keys.

**Dictionaries:** Plain Object used as a dictionary for the advantage of the fast lookup. Mentioned separate, because it's a different state of mind, having/dealing with a dictionary of items and dealing with an Object composing some properties.

**Objects:** A composition of properties of "some object". Like the body parts of a person. Or the "row" in a table of data: `{id, firstName, lastName, ...}`
Avoid enumerated properties. If you have sth. like `{foo1, foo2, foo3, ...}` `foo` is most likely a list of whatever, and should be built as such (just makes your life easier). 
*unless this object is a dictionary*