# Link data between two json from WP REST API

Tags: json, wordpress, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an app developed using *ionic 2*, is about quotes. I want to manage the quotes (and authors, categories, etc) with *Wordpress* and his *REST API*. At first instance i used normal posts, but now i am trying with custom post types, becouse that gives me more control and organization in the backend, so i have one CPT for `quotes` and other for `authors`, and a relation between them.

Example ↓

**wp-json/wp/v2/quotes**

```
[
  {
    id: 79,
    x_metadata: {
      custom_post_type_onomies_relationship: "77",
      quote: "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken"
    }
  }
]
```

**wp-json/wp/v2/authors**

```
[
  {
    id: 77,
    title: {
      rendered: "Oscar Wilde"
    },
    x_metadata: {
      bio: "https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Wilde"
    }
  }
]
```

Like you can see, the relation is in `custom_post_type_onomies_relationship`, but i don't know how to merge this data properly in the app (in which i use Angular 2/Typescript).

The only way i can think is loop through the quotes, for every quote loop through authors checking ids, and then add the data from the author inside the quotes array. Is that okey or is there any other way more efficient?

Thanks in advance and sorry if my english is not perfect.

Comment: Wordpress has so many tables that is only for relationships. They are required to `many-to-many` structures. When I used wordpress as API, I made my own back-end with `ruby on rails`, but I had access to the database.

You must search about `many-to-many` relationship. These loops are not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_embed` request for author

`wp-json/wp/v2/quotes?_embed=`

[see embedding](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/linking-and-embedding/#embedding)

### updated

the embed resources are available only for certain fields (eg. post's author, replies)

> The only way i can think is loop through the quotes, for every quote
>   loop through authors checking ids, and then add the data from the
>   author inside the quotes array.

if you want some linked data that not included (embeddable) the common pattern to minimize REST API calls is getting list of all authors then create array map of author_id -> authors stored in client

- nested loop performance is `O(n^2)`
- loop through the quotes then doing indexed search (`authors[id]` or  `Array.indexOf`) performance is `O(n*logn)`

more: [array search performance in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript)