# How to find selected objects from an object

Tags: javascript

I have seasons object and `selectedSeasonIds` which holds data whether selected key is selected or not.

I'm refactoring the array to object data structure for better performance.

I want to render ONLY selected season while I have these data

```
seasons  = {30: 'Fall', 31: 'Spring', 32: 'All'}

selectedSeasonIds = {30: true, 31: false, 32: true}

let output = selectedSeasonIds.????
// {30: 'Fall', 32: 'All'} <- This is my goal
```

I used the selector to select the selected objects. But I don't see any benefit of using it.Please feel free to use my code or create better one. Here is my snippet of my code

Here is my **selector**.

```
const getSeasons = (seasons, selectedSeasonIds) => {
  const selectedSeasons = _.filter(
    seasons,
    season => _.includes(selectedSeasonIds, season.id)
  );
  return selectedSeasons;
}
```

I'm getting selected objects from selector

```
selectedSeasons = SelectedSeasonsSelector(this.state) << getting selector
if(selectedSeasons.length==0) {
    return '-'
}
let seasonList = selectedSeasons.map((season) => {
    return ' '+season.value;
})
return seasonList
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why would an object look-up be more performant than an array look-up?

Comment: Because object look-up is much faster than array look up. I had an issue with slow Touchable Opacity. Hopefully after refactoring it solves the problem :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not faster, in JS everything is possible, though.

Comment: Here you see it's about 50 times faster than array search. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript

Comment: My array search takes about 1000ms, hopefully it goes down to about 100ms.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked post starts with "_The short version: Arrays are mostly faster than objects ..._". Afaik the only exception of this is a sparse array, which you should avoid anyway. Maybe you better to ask what's wrong/how to improve the slow array search you have ..?

Comment: Good point. But I don't understand because the rest of answer shows only the case for fast object search.

Comment: Now I'm confused.

Comment: There has to be something wrong in your array search. Just for an example, I daily use an old hta, which reads a 500 kB JSON file from an intranet server, checks, whether it has exactly the same data as an exisiting variable, creates a 2D array (~3000x15) from the data, searches for a string from a column, stores all the matching strings and finally creates an unique drawing number. All this within 60 - 70 milliseconds, and with IE, which is not the fastest browser in the west.

Comment: Actually you were right. I just finished the refactoring and it didn't improve my performance. This is quite frustrating. Is it ok for me to open another question for you? I will post it tomorrow, and I need your help!!! :)

Comment: You can very well post another question (not only for me, though), since it's totally another topic, though the data would be the same. I forgot to mention in my previous comment, that the process also decodes urlencoded content of the entire array too.

Comment: I didn't recognize this problem on my emulator but when I tested on my actual device, it's soooo laggy. It takes 1 second to finish the process. Thanks. I will let you know soon.

Comment: @Teemu I hope you can help me on this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162106/touchableopacity-takes-about-1000ms-can-you-diagnose-my-code

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm totally handless with React.

Comment: It's cool. have a good day

Comment: maybe bring your friends who know React :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and put a condition to only add those values in output which have `true` in `selectedSeasonIds`.

```js
const seasons  = {30: 'Fall', 31: 'Spring', 32: 'All'};
const selectedSeasonIds = {30: true, 31: false, 32: true};
let output = Object.keys(selectedSeasonIds).reduce((r,k) => {
  if(selectedSeasonIds[k])
    r[k] = seasons[k] || '';
  return r;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Could you explain what the r is??

Comment: `r` is the accumulator object which will store the key value. `k` is the keys in `selectedSeasonIds`.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in an object are accessible properties and can be gotten like so:

```
selectedSeasonIds = {30: true, 31: false, 32: true}
Object.keys(selectedSeasonIds); //Gets an array of keys
for (let key in selectedSeasonIds){//Iterate through the keys};
```

Afterwards it should be trivial to access the selected seasons.

Comment: Thanks for your input but it's hard to consider this as a complete answer.