# Are js array indexes set if not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am working on a script in which i need some data based on a lot of timestamps.

Below is just an example

```
var timestampData1 = [1555486016,1555486017,1555486018...]; 
var timestampData2 = [1555486016,1555486017,1555486018...];

var data = [];
data[1] = [];
$.each(timestampData1,function(index,value) {
    data[1][value] = 1;
});
data[2] = [];
$.each(timestampData2,function(index,value) {
    data[2][value] = 1;
});
console.log(data);
```

The example above will output the following in the console

[image]

However if i examine the data in the console, i see a lot of empty sets counting from 0 up to the very last timestamp

[image]

So my question is:

Will javascript set all of these indexes, or is it simply an indication in the console?
If not, i guess that it is very bad for performance, doing it like above ?

Comment: The array indexes are automatically set

Comment: Express the index as a string if you don't want this to happen.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Although this: `data[1555486016]` is different from this: `data['1555486016']`

Comment: What's your end goal here? There may be a much simpler answer...

Comment: Your array is a sparse array [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript)

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Indexes cannot be strings. They must always be non-negative whole numbers. If you want strings, you need to create an object.

Comment: A['hello'] is a valid array expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your assumption is correct. If you use objects which have key/value pairs whis won't be a problem, however you will you array methods like `push` and `filter`.

Example:

```
var timestampData1 = [1555486016,1555486017,1555486018...]; 
var timestampData2 = [1555486016,1555486017,1555486018...];

var data = [];
//Make data[1] an object not array
data[1] = {};
$.each(timestampData1,function(index,value) {
    data[1][value] = 1;
});
//Make data[1] an object not array
data[2] = {};
$.each(timestampData2,function(index,value) {
    data[2][value] = 1;
});
console.log(data);
```

Output:

[image]