# Is an array of objects more inefficient than a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, hashmap

When dealing with a large number of data points, is an array of objects a poor choice to use? Is it inefficient to perform lookups when the data is in this format?

```
var list = [
    { date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
    { date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
    { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];
```

Would it be more efficient to have it in the form of a unifying hash table?

```
var dict = {
    Item 1: {date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
    Item 2: {date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
    Item 3: {date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
};
```

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array vs. Object efficiency in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript)