# read folder values and if folder is unique, add object to array, otherwise increase count on object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a directory with many sub-directories, which in turn have multiple sub-directories. Think along the lines of

```
vvv
  example1
    plugin1
    plugin2
  example2
    plugin1
    plugin2
    plugin3
  etc.
```

I want to determine how many times a plugin name exists, and add the plugin to an array of objects if it hasn't already been added. For the case where it has in fact been added, each plugin object contains a key "count" with a numeric value representing how many times the plugin folder name has been found:

```
[
  {name: "plugin1", count: 5},
  {name: "plugin2", count: 2},
  etc.
]
```

I get that this is likely fairly easy, but I cannot come up with proper, dry code past pushing the first instance of a plugin name to an array. I am reading directories from a file system:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {    
    const main = fs.readdirSync("./vvv");
    const newArr = [];

    main.forEach((dir) => {
      const plugins = fs.readdirSync(`./vvv/${dir}`);

      plugins.forEach((plugin, index) => {
        newArr.push({ name: plugin, count: 0 });
      });
    });

    console.log(newArr, "newArr");

    res.end();
  })
  .listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running at port 3000...");
  });
```

I think the way would be a reduce function to keep the code as dry as possible, but not sure how to get there.

Codesandbox is giving me readDir trouble, so not sure how to provide an easy working example of the above base-code.

Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding each entry as unique, not filtering existing ones.

**Note:** As in initial question, following examples lack error handling. Non async examples (all but the last) would need `try {} catch(err) {}` blocks. Async examples may use them as well, or `Promise.prototype.catch` chained after `then` blocks.

#### You might use an object instead

```js
    const main = fs.readdirSync("./vvv");
    const newArr = {}; // Object, not array

    main.forEach((dir) => {
      const plugins = fs.readdirSync(`./vvv/${dir}`);

      plugins.forEach((plugin, index) => {
        if(plugin in newArr) {
          newArr[plugin]++;
        }
        else {
          newArr[plugin] = 1;
        }
      });
    });
```

#### Or use `Array.find`

```js
    const main = fs.readdirSync("./vvv");
    const newArr = [];

    main.forEach((dir) => {
      const plugins = fs.readdirSync(`./vvv/${dir}`);

      plugins.forEach((plugin, index) => {
        const found = newArr.find(p => p.name === plugin);
        if(found) {
          found.count++;
        }
        else {
          newArr.push({ name: plugin, count: 1 });
        }
      });
    });
```

#### You can use `Array.reduce`

```js
    const main = fs.readdirSync("./vvv");
    const newArr = main.reduce((acc, dir) => {
      const plugins = fs.readdirSync(`./vvv/${dir}`);

      plugins.forEach((plugin, index) => {
        const found = acc.find(p => p.name === plugin);
        if(found) {
          found.count++;
        }
        else {
          acc.push({ name: plugin, count: 1 });
        }
      });

      return acc;
    }, []);
```

#### You can use double `Array.reduce` and object, immutable

```js
    const main = fs.readdirSync("./vvv");
    const newArr = main.reduce((acc, dir) => (
      fs.readdirSync(`./vvv/${dir}`)
        .reduce((accInner, plugin) => ({
           // Return all already collected plugins
           ...accInner,
           // For the currently handled plugin...
           [plugin]: (plugin in accInner)
             // If already in othe object, return its value + 1
             ? accInner[plugin] + 1
             // If not, create it with a 1 counter
             : 1,
         }), acc) // Initialize accInner to acc
    ), {}); // Object, not array
```

#### You can use double `Array.reduce` and `Array.find`, immutable

```js
    const main = fs.readdirSync("./vvv");
    const newArr = main.reduce((acc, dir) => (
      fs.readdirSync(`./vvv/${dir}`)
        .reduce((accInner, plugin) => (
           accInner.find(p => p.name === plugin)
             // If a plugin with that name is found in inner accumulator,
             // return a map of that accumulator, modifiying the current
             // plugin (count+1) and passing through the rest
             ? accInner.map(p =>
                 p.name === plugin
                   ? {...p, count: p.count + 1}
                   : p
               )
             // If none is found, return a new array with all the 
             // collected plugins, plus the new one
             : [...accInner, {name: plugin, count: 1}]
         ), acc) // Initialize accInner to acc
    ), []); // Array
```

#### You can use double `Array.reduce` and `Array.find`, immutable, using `async`/`await` and async version on `fs`

In this example, the workflow should:

- Launch and wait for resolution of `main`'s `readdir`: we cannot do anything until having its results
- Launch all `readdir` simultaneously/in parallel. All IO operations start their job here.
- Use [`reduce` technique for resolving promises sequentially](https://css-tricks.com/why-using-reduce-to-sequentially-resolve-promises-works/). Waits until the first `main`'s array element `readdir` promise is fulfilled to start parsing all promises results, some of which may need some extra waiting.
- Use `reduce` to compute values as in the previous example.

```js
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs").promises;

// You can only run async code (using `await` keyword) inside an async function
// You can use use `await` without an extra function declaring your package as a module in `package.json`

const getPluginsUsage = async () => {
  const main = await fs.readdir("./vvv");
  // Wait for all the `then` chain to fulfill
  const newArr = await main
    // Generate an array of promises from the `main` array of dirs
    // All IO operations start here, concurrently/in parallel
    .map( dir => fs.readdir(`./vvv/${dir}`))
    .reduce((prev, promise) => ( 
      // Once initial/previous promise fulfills,
      // add current promise to the `then` chain.
      //  - Get `acc` from previous promise resolution
      //  - Get `plugins` from current promise resolution

      // Note: Async functions return a promise
      //       resolving to its return value
      // This block could also be written as:
      // async (prev, promise) => {
      //   const acc = await prev;
      //   const plugins = await promise;
      //   return plugins.reduce(...);
      // }

      // Or:
      // prev
      //   .then( acc => promise.then( plugins => [acc, plugins] ))
      //   .then( ([acc, plugin]) => plugins.reduce(..) ) 

      // Or:
      // async (prev, promise) => {
      //   const [acc, plugins] = await Promise.all([prev, promise]);
      //   return plugins.reduce(...);
      // }

      prev.then( acc => promise.then( plugins => ( 
        // Parse results as in the previous example
        plugins.reduce( (accInner, plugin) => ( 
          acc.find(p => p.name === plugin)
            ? accInner.map(p =>
                p.name === plugin
                  ? {...p, count: p.count + 1}
                  : p 
              ) 
            : [...accInner, {name: plugin, count: 1}]
        ), acc)
      )))

    // Initial reduce value is a Promise that will resolve
    // to our accumulator base (here, an empty Array)
    ), Promise.resolve([]));

  // Async functions always return a promise
  // This one will resolve to newArr value
  return newArr;
} 

// Using node module package will probably make it easier to handle the http server (this next part is not tested)
getPluginsUsage().then( newArr => {
  http
    .createServer(function (req, res) {    
      console.log({newArr});
      res.end();
    })
    .listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Server is running at port 3000...");
    });
});
```

If you feel wild, you can also try [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`WeakSet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet).

### Edit

Further JavaScript readings:

- [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...`:

  - Array destructuring: `...[]`
  - Object destructuring: `...{}`
  - Cloning with `{ ...{} }` and `[ ...[] ]`
- `Array` methods:

  - [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
  - [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
  - [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [The `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
- [The ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `() ? () : ()`
- [Async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- StackOverflow: [Array vs. Object efficiency in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17295727/2928168). Look into the linked [benchmark](https://jsben.ch/Y9jDP).

General programming concepts:

- [Functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and a specific [JavaScript tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-programming-in-javascript-explained-in-plain-english/) and [another one](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/functional-javascript)
- [Immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)
- [The MapReduce programming model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed solutions and explanation. I found the first two methods excellent and so easy that I'm embarrassed that I couldn't get this by myself. The only thing to add is that I believe I'd have to start the count at `newArr[plugin] = 1;` for `You might use an object instead`, and `newArr2.push({ name: plugin, count: 1 });` for the `Array.find` method, rather than 0, otherwise I'm down by one in the total count. I couldn't get any reduce methods to work. Think the wrong folder is being considered, but also `dir` remains undefined even if adjusted for right folders.

Comment: You are right about `0` and `1`. Just fixed all the answers.

Comment: Tested all of them. There was a problem in the 3rd solution (the first with `reduce`), where the `return acc` was misplaced. Now fixed.

Comment: I tested with Node v12.18.2 (Linux). Which version and operating system are you using?

Comment: I don't know if it was your fix or something on my end but now all of them work like a charm. Thanks a lot for your time and effort. If I wanted to get a better understanding about the concepts you've employed here, what topic should I be looking into? What structural/architectural problem are you addressing here?

Comment: Edit: added references to global programming concepts and specific for JavaScript.

Comment: I can also add an example taking advantage of `async`/`await` using non-sync `fs` method, allowing to accomplish the task faster when the plugins tree is very large (or just for fun and educational purposes).

Comment: For completeness I'd like to encourage you to add the `async`/`await` example as well. Although I use them all the time I think if others found this post it would add a lot of value. I'll buy you a beer regardless.

Comment: Just added the `async` response ;)