# React Redux - Issue removing an item

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on implementing beautiful-dnd in my react project.

**I have the following data:**

```
const initialData = {
        users: {
            'user-1': { id: 'user-1', name: 'John'},
            'user-2': { id: 'user-2', name: 'Patrick'},
            'user-3': { id: 'user-3', name: 'Malorie'},
            'user-4': { id: 'user-4', name: 'Eric'},
            'user-5': { id: 'user-5', name: 'Bob'},
            'user-6': { id: 'user-6', name: 'Blob'}
        },
        areas: {
            'area-0': {
                id: 'area-0',
                title: 'Main Area',
                userIds: ['user-1', 'user-2', 'user-3', 'user-4', 'user-5', 'user-6']
            },
            'area-1': {
                id: 'area-1',
                title: 'Area 1',
                userIds: []
            },
            'area-2': {
                id: 'area-2',
                title: 'Area 2',
                userIds: []
            }
        },
        areaOrder: ['area-0', 'area-1', 'area-2'],
    }
```

In the reducer, I try to remove one of the users this way:

```
case REMOVE_USER_ACTION:
    return {
        ...state,
        users: [ ...state.users.filter(user => user !== action.id) ]
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: e.users.filter is not a function or its return
> value is not iterable

I searched for this error, but I'm unable to find a comparable scenario and how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't filter the `state.users` if your data is an object. It's either you change the initialData shape or if it's really like that, then you'd have to do some way to delete a key from your object.

```
case REMOVE_USER_ACTION:
    const users = { ...state.users };
    delete users[action.id];
    return {
        ...state,
        users,
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: e.users.filter is not a function or its return value is not
> iterable

It means that `users` is not an array, it's `object` instead.

So you can get the filtered users in this way:

```js
const users = {'user-1':{id:'user-1',name:'John'},'user-2':{id:'user-2',name:'Patrick'},'user-3':{id:'user-3',name:'Malorie'},'user-4':{id:'user-4',name:'Eric'},'user-5':{id:'user-5',name:'Bob'},'user-6':{id:'user-6',name:'Blob'}};

const actionId = "user-1";
const filteredUsers = Object.entries(users).filter(([key, value]) => value.id != actionId);
console.log(Object.fromEntries(filteredUsers));
```

As a result, your `REMOVE_USER_ACTION` looks like

```
case REMOVE_USER_ACTION:
    return {
        ...state,
        users: filteredUsers
    }
```

---

**However,** you should change `users` type from `object` to `array` in terms of *performance, meaningful name & clean code.*

```js
const users = [{ id: 'user-1', name: 'John'},
         { id: 'user-2', name: 'Patrick'},
         { id: 'user-3', name: 'Malorie'},
         { id: 'user-4', name: 'Eric'},
         { id: 'user-5', name: 'Bob'},
         { id: 'user-6', name: 'Blob'}
       ];
       
const actionId = "user-1";
const filteredUsers = users.filter(item => item.id != actionId);
console.log(filteredUsers);
```

Comment: I disagree that it should be an array.  A keyed object makes lookup operations much easier.

Comment: Agree. To be more precise. *If you want to supply `specific keys`, the only choice is an `object`. If you `don't care about the keys, an array it is.*  [Array vs. Object efficiency in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript) @LindaPaiste

Answer (score 1):

`users` is an object, not an array, so you can't iterate over it

Here is a possible solution using `Object.entries`

```
case REMOVE_USER_ACTION:
  return {
    ...state,
    users: Object.entries(state.users).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      if (key !== action.id) {
        acc[key] = value;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})
  }
```