# Array vs Object performance javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

Ex: I have a list off `User` object. Each user have an **unique id**.

```
{
  id: 'someid' // uuid,
  name: 'username',
  //... more
}
```

My question is: Array or Object will be better for list of User.

If use array:

```
[
  {
      id: 'someid1' // uuid,
      name: 'username',
      //... more
  },
  {
      id: 'someid2' // uuid,
      name: 'username',
      //... more
  },
]
```

If use Object:

```
{
  someid1: {
    name: 'username',
    // ... more
  },
  someid2: {
    name: 'username',
    // ... more
  }
}
```

If I use Object, I can use userId as key(unique).
When i want access to a user: `users.userid1`

If I use Array. I must find first: `users.find(user => user.id === 'someid1')`

It seem Array doing more than Object (find()).

If I have a lot of user (thousands or millions), the `find()` take longer to get 1 user.

I dont know how exactly javascript work behind.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript

Comment: Object property lookup will be much faster than array traversal. But there's a third option you haven't listed: [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). See that article for [a comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps) of using an object vs. using a `Map`.